# What did Lefors represent?

Tags: analysis, butch-cassidy-and-the-sundance-kid

So I was watching ***Butch Cassidy and The Sundance Kid*** (1969) and noticed that Joe Lefors, who was a major terror for Butch and Co., never comes into focus and is treated as an absolute worry

> until the end in which they joke about.

So I was wondering if he was a representation of anything other than just the law?

> Was the comment at the end a realization to indicate that whatever he represented was not actually as bad as they believed?

I might be reading too much into this, as it is based on a mostly true story, but any information is helpful

Comment: [The posse did include Lefors, but not Baltimore – he didn’t exist. The film’s long, inescapable pursuit across the west is fictional. The real Cassidy easily evaded the posse.](https://www.theguardian.com/film/filmblog/2013/jul/11/butch-cassidy-sundance-kid-reel-history)

Comment: I wonder if spoiler tags are necessary for a (nearly) fifty-year-old movie, especially when it's based on a true story, but the concern over people's sensitivity toward spoilers is admirable :)

Comment: I always felt the recurring theme of the movie was the death of the Old West. LeFors represents the unyielding march of time and the spread of modernity into the once unruly territory. Like when they play with the new-fangled bicycle and, in the end, reject it, Butch and Sundance represent the old ways that hold out as long as they can, but are ultimately doomed by their inability to conform.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a crack at answering my own question as it's been some time.

So after doing some googling I've found a few articles that claim Butch Cassidy and The Sundance Kid is symbolic of idealized manliness. If this is true then I would conjecture that LeFors is merely the law man the biggest toughest guy in the room that they cannot overcome but are able to elude putting them on par with Lefors as far as manliness goes.

However when watching the movie myself I tend to take the main duos actions more so as childish and whimsy. Constantly jesting and playing tricks even in serious moments. To that effect I would venture that Lefors is more so a stern father figure or figure of maturity that they are always eluding. This is primarily due to the fact that Butch mentions if they get caught they'd go to jail instead of hanged which given the time/decade and the lot of crimes they've committed, Sundance having even killed people, would seem odd. Instead it is more of a disciplinary/corrective action
In the end, still being the playful bunch unwilling to hold down/given up on a job, they are more concerned of Lefors, maturing, and embrace the ideal childish fantasy of guns blazing youthful joy is more fun than facing the scrutiny of labor/maturity.

But then again this is just my own conjecture/analysis.
But then again this is based on a true story and maybe the author just wanted Lefors to be Lefors and just threw him in.